# PHP MySQL Arrays, how can I obtain a specific structure for an API?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to obtain the following data structure from a MySQL query via PHP, and array creation (this is going to be sent via JSON to an API):

```
Array ( [stock_sym] => KEY [stock_name] => Name [last_val] => Price ) 
Array ( [stock_sym] => GOOG [stock_name] => Google [last_val] => 76.92) 
Array ( [stock_sym] => AAPL [stock_name] => Apple Inc. [last_val] => 123.59)
```

That is, unique separate arrays containing 3 or more elements with values.

Using the following code I'm getting an additional (useless) array with values I am not able to get rid of neither by merging nor by flattening.

```
[connection data above this line]

$fetch = mysql_query("select key, name, price from data where price > 0 and key in('GOOG','AAPL') order by date asc"); 


$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
    $return_arr[] = array();
    $row_array['stock_sym'] = $row['price'];
    $row_array['stock_name'] = $row['oq_id'];
    $row_array['last_val'] = $row['price'];

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

The above code brings back the following structure:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [stock_sym] => Key [stock_name] => Name [last_val] => Price ) 
        [1] => Array ( [stock_sym] => GOOG [stock_name] => Google [last_val] => 54.8900 )  
        [2] => Array ( [stock_sym] => AAPL [stock_name] => Apple Inc. [last_val] => 154.55 ) 
      )
```

I am trying to plug into an API with as minimum string and UI manipulation as possible so it is quite important to keep the data structure above.

I'm sure I can do this in several ways, but can you guys point me to the easiest/most efficient one?

Thanks so much in advance for your help.
Best regards,

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
    $return_arr[] = array();
    $row_array['stock_sym'] = $row['price'];
    $row_array['stock_name'] = $row['oq_id'];
    $row_array['last_val'] = $row['price'];

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$array1 = json_encode($return_arr[0]);
$array2 = json_encode($return_arr[1]);
$array3 = json_encode($return_arr[2]);
```